# How to make sure one cronjob is run after another cronjob is completed?

Tags: cron

I need to run two cronjobs. One is to run in every 20 minutes every day from 1AM to   midnight. Then the second job is scheduled to run at midnight.

```
  */20 1-23 * * * root [job1]
  0 0 * * * root [joob2]
```

However, I need to make sure that job 2 is completed when job 1 is run again.
How can I do this?

Comment: Why not write a script that runs one after another?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with *I need to make sure that job 2 is completed when job 1 is run again.* Do you mean that Job2 can only run after job1 of 00:00 finished running?

Comment: @kvantour - I need Job1 to run in every 20 minutes every day starting from 1AM, then in midnight it should be stopped. Job2 will start at midnight, but it could be taking a long period of time to get it complete, for example, it may still run when it is 1AM. Then I don't need to run Job1, while Job 2 is still running. I need to start Job 1 as soon as Job 2 is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you might be after

```
*/20 1-23 * * * root while [ ! -e $HOME/jobmarker ]; do sleep 5; done && command_job1
0    0    * * * root rm $HOME/jobmarker && command_job2 && touch $HOME/jobmarker
```

This will only run job1 if the file `$HOME/jobmarker` exists. If not, it will wait until it is generated.
The second job will first remove the marker, run the command and then set the marker again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to make job 2 create a flag file (eg `touch`) when starting, which it will remove when it's completed. 
Then job11 should check if the file exists and make it exit / don't run if it exists.  Or sleep for a specified amount of time and then try again.